# Creating pdf files with inline images with (py) Cairo

Tags: python, pdf, cairo, pango

What is the method to write images inline (without breaking the paragraph) using cairo +  pango + python
ie. Image should be able to place within paragraph.

Comment: Also , is there any good py-cairo tutorial??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-pangolayout.html#method-pangolayout--set-wrap)